# Web2Py - How to use SELECT query with WHERE.. IN keyword

Tags: python, sql, web2py

I have a table called `User` and in Web2Py I would to get Users that match certain ids say (1,5,11,16).

Do I have to write SQL query itself or can it be elegantly done using Web2Py style queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [belongs](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#belongs) operator